# Google-Cloud-Speech: Latency in first interim result for StreamingRecognize method

Tags: java, google-cloud-speech

We are trying to use Google StreamingRecognize method via JAVA client. We are reading data from microphone and sending it to the speech API. 
Following settings are used:
Recognition Config - LINEAR16, 16KHz, en-US
We tried pushing different buffer size to StreamingRecognize (upto 16000 bytes).
We observe that it takes a minimum of 4-5 seconds to get the first result and there after interim results are streamed.
Can anybody confirm if this is the intended behavior of the API. Also it would be nice to know why so much latency is there.
Is there any method or work around to minimize the latency.

Please note that after the latency we get the interim result and finally the full utterance with reasonable accuracy

Comment: I *suspect* it's waiting to get some context before producing the first interim results.

Comment: Any guess on what the context could be and if it is possible to minimize the delay due to context. Android SpeechRecognizer seems to be working fine.

Comment: The context of the whole utterance, basically. I don't know whether the Android SpeechRecognizer uses the same technology *at all* - and it may well be optimized for very different scenarios (e.g. a few words vs many sentences). I'm not sure whether I've still got my C# streaming Speech app around - it's been a while since I've used it. I remember there being a bit of a delay to start with, but it didn't seem huge, and I doubt that it was 4-5 seconds. If I get time, I'll try to find it and reproduce.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I understand the "context" that you were referring to. It makes sense that some context would be needed to predict better interim results. I am looking at max ~1sec latency before I start getting interim results. In case your streaming speech works, I would love to get the reference implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect 2 behaviors are wrong in context of description,

1. Sample rate should not be hardcoded or fixed constant in your java service app, because samplerate will be varied for every system or microphone adapters installed in respective system. i.e, 8000, 16000, 41000, 48000 , etc. so you need to pick sample rate from audio context of your microphone and send it in 1st initial call to update in Requestconfig setter.
2. If you are streaming through websocket at the time of connection handshake send those samplerate, bytes/frame to 1st request observer and from 2nd request onwards you need to skip 1st request observers and can pass directly to 2nd request observers to get transcript.

If above points doesn't work share your StreamingRecognize class. So i can tune your code accordingly